# Symmetry of second derivatives: Can we conclude $({\rm D}_2({\rm D}_1f)(x)h_2)h_1'=({\rm D}_1({\rm D}_2f)(x)h_1)h_2'$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, derivatives, frechet-derivative

Let $E_i$ be a normed $\mathbb R$-vector space.

From Schwarz's theorem we know that if $\Omega\subseteq E_1$ is open and $f:\Omega\to E_2$ is twice differentiable at $x\in\Omega$, then ${\rm D}^2f(x)$ is symmetric; i.e. $${\rm D}^2f(x)(h,h')={\rm D}^2f(x)(h',h)\tag1$$ for all $h,h'\in E_1$.

Now suppose $\Omega\subseteq E_1\times E_2$ and $f:\Omega\to E_3$ is twice differentiable at $x\in\Omega$. Can we deduce that $$({\rm D}_2({\rm D}_1f)(x)h_2)h_1'=({\rm D}_1({\rm D}_2f)(x)h_1)h_2'\tag2$$ for all $h,h'\in E_1\times E_2$, where ${\rm D}_i$ denotes the Fréchet derivative with respect to the $i$th argument, from Schwarz's theorem?

Comment: No, the formula is wrong; there shouldn't be any primes (the two sides are completely independent the way you've written things. for example I can set $h_2=0$, so the LHS is $0$, but the RHS need not be $0$). It should be $(D_2D_1f)_x(h_2)(h_1)=(D_1D_2f)_x(h_1)(h_2)$. i.e after you canonically identify $(D_2D_1f)_x$ and $(D_1D_2f)_x$ with bilinear maps $E_1\times E_2\to E_3$, you can swap the order of derivatives $D_1D_2=D_2D_1$.

Comment: @peek-a-boo Huh? I can't follow. Isn't your formula the same as mine? The prime in $h'$ is not a derivative. I've just chosen $h'$ as a symbol for an element in $E_1\times E_2$. Maybe I've confused you with that?!

Comment: @peek-a-boo On a second look, your formula is different. But please note that my $h,h'$ are in $E_1\times E_2$. What are your $h_1,h_2$? Maybe I should note that what I've actually tried to do is simplify $${\rm D}^2f(x)(h,h')=({\rm D_1}({\rm D}_1f)(x)h_1)h_1'+({\rm D_2}({\rm D}_1f)(x)h_2)h_1'+({\rm D_1}({\rm D}_2f)(x)h_1)h_2'+({\rm D_2}({\rm D}_2f)(x)h_2)h_2'.$$ I guess the only possible simplification is $$({\rm D_2}({\rm D}_1f)(x)h_2)h_1'+({\rm D_1}({\rm D}_2f)(x)h_1)h_2'=({\rm D_1}({\rm D}_2f)(x)h_1)h_2'+({\rm D_1}({\rm D}_2f)(x)h_2)h_1').$$

Comment: I understood your notation just fine. I'm denoting $h_1\in E_1, h_2\in E_2$. Anyway for the formula you wrote, use it in the special case $h=(h_1,0)$ and $h'=(0,h_2')$. Then three out of the four terms vanish. Next, apply symmetry and you'll see that $(D_1D_2f)_x(h_1)(h_2')=(D_2D_1f)_x(h_2')(h_1)$. I'll I've done in my previous comment is say that since $h_2'$ is an arbitrary element of $E_2$, the extra prime is unnecessary baggage so I renamed the dummy variable as $h_2$. So, this is completely equivalent to what I wrote in my first comment, but different from your (2).

Comment: Your (2) is wrong, it should be $(D_2(D_1f)(x) \cdot h_2') \cdot h_1 = (D_1(D_2f)(x) \cdot h_1) \cdot h_2',$ which is what peek-a-boo stated.